# shortcode content is showed twice or at the bottom of the page

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have a problem with my shortcode, it should appear in the post div but instead it is showed at the end of the page content(at the bottom of the page).
 This is the code:

```
add_shortcode('registru', "show_registru");

function show_registru()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $list_inregistrari = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'wprc_ong_casa ORDER BY data_inregistrare ASC');
    $sold_init = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT valoare FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'wprc_solduri LIMIT 1');

    ob_start();
    print_table($list_inregistrari, $sold_init);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

If I try to use **ob_get_content()** instead of **ob_get_clean()** the table will be showed two times once in the post div and once at the bottom of the page.

I also tried doing this(and it is still at the bottom of the page):

```
ob_start();
print_table($list_inregistrari, $sold_init);
$return = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();
return $return;
```

*The **print_table** function just echoes some HTML code, so I also tried to put all the strings with HTML code into a single variable and then return it, but still nothing.

Comment: Welcome! Please consider to reduce the code example to the items which are essentially neccessary to reproduce the problem. This will help identifying the problem here.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong yet. Have you tried running with WP_DEBUG turned on to see if there are any errors? https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: I use WP_DEBUG and there is no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! So the problem was your  element in `print_table` was missing an ending `</table>` tag.

Try this for your function (note the 2nd to last line):

```
        </tr>
    <?php

        endforeach;

        front_table_footer($total_incasari, $total_plati, $sold_init);

        echo '</table>'; // needs a closing tag
}
```

Comment: THANKS a lot! That was the problem :))